# How to plot Quantum Wave-Funktions like $e^{ix^2}$

Tags: plotting, complex

I would like to Plot a function like $e^{ix^2}$, similar to the one seen in this video at 1:26: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p7bzE1E5PMY&t=86s.
I think what I'm trying to do is to plot the imaginary part on one axis, and the real part on the other, both as a function of x.
Does anybody know how that works? I hope it isn't to complicated, since this isn't my task, just trying to boost my understanding of quantum mechanics.

Comment: The video and your description don't correspond. The video plots pos. vs. vel., not real and imaginary parts.  Which do you want? Possibly useful functions: `ReIm[]`, `ParametricPlot[]`, `ParametricPlot3D[]`.

Comment: @MichaelE2:  The OP unwittingly linked to a later time-stamp in the video than they intended to.  I've corrected the URL.

Comment: @MichaelSeifert Ah, thanks. I have little patience with video explanations as well. So already put out by a non-self-contained Q, I gave up.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry for that, didn't realise there was a time stamp in the hyperlink @MichaelE2. Thanks for correcting it Michael Seifert.

Answer (score 2):

As noted in the comments, the function you want is `ParametricPlot3D`.  You create the "graph" as a parametric curve with `x` as the parameter, and whose `y` and `z` coordinates are $\Re(\psi)$ and $\Im(\psi)$ respectively.

```
psi[x_] = Exp[I x^2];
ParametricPlot3D[{x, Re[psi[x]], Im[psi[x]]}, {x, -3, 3}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Ticks -> {Automatic, None, None}, Boxed -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: for fun you could add `ParametricPlot3D[{x, Re[psi[x]], Im[psi[x]]} // Evaluate, {x, -3, 3}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0, 0}, Ticks -> {Automatic, None, None}, 
 Boxed -> False, ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[z]]]'

Comment: @chris:  probably `ColorFunctionScaling -> False, 
 ColorFunction -> Function[{x, y, z}, Hue[Arg[psi[x]]/(2 \[Pi])]]]` would have more physical meaning, but let's walk before we run.  :-)

Comment: Awesome, that was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks for taking your time!